# Saving SelectControl option

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I have managed to create a WordPress custom Gutenberg block and I've created a panel section to store all my blocks options.

However, I am very new to react and I've managed to scaffold this together. I'm trying to give this select an initial state and also save the state when changed.

I know I need to do something with withState but I'm not sure I can see my promise is failing is that but I'm not sure why.

```
// Block Options
const withInspectorControls =  createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
  return (props) => {
    const size = {size:"display-2"};
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <BlockEdit { ...props } />
        <InspectorControls>
          <PanelBody title="Display Block Settings"
            icon="welcome-widgets-menus"
            initialOpen={ true }
          >
            <SelectControl
              label="Display Size"
              value={size}
              options={[
                { label: 'Display 1', value: 'display-1' },
                { label: 'Display 2', value: 'display-2' },
                { label: 'Display 3', value: 'display-3' },
                { label: 'Display 4', value: 'display-4' },
              ]}
              onChange={ ( size ) => { setState( { size:size } ) } } 
            />
          </PanelBody>
        </InspectorControls>
      </Fragment>
    );
  };
}, "withInspectorControl" );

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockEdit', 'display-heading/with-inspector-controls', withInspectorControls );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. As you already mentioned you really just need to add the `withState` HOC. This could look like this:

```js
// 1. add the withState import
import { withState } from '@wordpress/compose';

// 2. wrap your SelectControl with the withState HOC
const MySelectControl = withState( {
    // this is your state, in this case display-2 would be the default
    size: 'display-2',
} )( ( { size, setState } ) => (
    <SelectControl
        label="Size"
        value={ size }
        options={ [
            { label: 'Display 1', value: 'display-1' },
            { label: 'Display 2', value: 'display-2' },
            { label: 'Display 3', value: 'display-3' },
            { label: 'Display 4', value: 'display-4' },
        ] }
        onChange={ ( size ) => { setState( { size } ) } }
    />
) );

// Block Options
const withInspectorControls =  createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
  return (props) => {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <BlockEdit { ...props } />
        <InspectorControls>
          <PanelBody title="Display Block Settings"
            icon="welcome-widgets-menus"
            initialOpen={ true }
          >
            // 3. now you can add your component in your panel
            <MySelectControl />
          </PanelBody>
        </InspectorControls>
      </Fragment>
    );
  };
}, "withInspectorControl" );

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockEdit', 'display-heading/with-inspector-controls', withInspectorControls );
```

Reacts Higher-Order Components can be really confusing in the beginning. But if you are familiar with the `OOP` paradigm, you can think of them like the `composition` pattern. The most important thing to know for Gutenberg development is the fact that they always return a new component. That's why I was able to use it like this `<MySelectControl />`.

Comment: Thank you @Orlandster for such an in-depth answer this worked!